# How many vptr will a object of class(uses single/multiple inheritance) have?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, vtable, vptr, memory-layout

How many vptrs are usually needed for a object whose clas( child ) has single inheritance with a base class which multiple inherits base1 and base2. What is the strategy for identifying how many vptrs a object has provided it has couple of single inheritance and multiple inheritance. Though standard doesn't specify about vptrs but I just want to know how an implementation does virtual function implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you care? The simple answer is *enough*, but I guess you want something more complete.

This is not part of the standard, so any implementation is free to do as they wish, but a general rule of thumb is that in an implementation that uses virtual table pointers, as a zeroth approximation, for the dynamic dispatch you need at most as many pointers to virtual tables as there are classes that **add** a new virtual method to the hierarchy. (In some cases the virtual table can be extended, and the base and derived types share a single `vptr`)

```
    // some examples:
    struct a { void foo(); };           // no need for virtual table
    struct b : a { virtual foo1(); };   // need vtable, and vptr
    struct c : b { void bar(); };       // no extra virtual table, 1 vptr (b) suffices
    struct d : b { virtual bar(); };    // 1 vtable, d extends b's vtable

    struct e : d, b {};                 // 2 vptr, 1 for the d and 1 for b                                      
    struct f : virtual b {};            // 1 vptr, f reuse b's vptr to locate subobject b
    struct g : virtual b {};            // 1 vptr, g reuse b's vptr to locate subobject b
    struct h : f, g {};                 // 2 vptr, 1 for f, 1 for g
                                        // h can locate subobject b using f's vptr
```

Basically each subobject of a type that requires its own dynamic dispatch (cannot directly reuse the parents) would need its own virtual table and vptr.

In reality compilers merge different vtables into a single vtable. When `d` adds a new virtual function over the set of functions in `b`, the compiler will merge the potential two tables into a single one by appending the new slots to the end of the vtable, so the vtable for `d` will be a extended version of the vtable for `b` with extra elements at the end maintaining binary compatibility (i.e. the `d` vtable can be interpreted as a `b` vtable to access the methods available in `b`), and the `d` object will have a single `vptr`.

In the case of multiple inheritance things become a bit more complicated as each base needs to have the same layout as a subobject of the complete object than if it was a separate object, so there will be extra vptrs pointing to different regions in the complete object's vtable.

Finally in the case of virtual inheritance things become even more complicated, and there might be multiple vtables for the same complete object with the vptr's being updated as construction/destruction evolves (vptr's are always updated as construction/destruction evolves, but without virtual inheritance the vptr will point to the base's vtables, while in the case of virtual inheritance there will be multiple vtables for the same type)

Comment: "`struct d : b { virtual bar(); };    // extra vtable, need b.vptr and d.vptr`" I don't think there is any compiler that introduces more than one vptr in a class with non-virtual SI.

Answer (score 5):

## The fine print

Anything regarding vptr/vtable is not specified, so this is going to be compiler dependent for the fine details, but the simple cases are handled the same by almost every modern compiler (I write "almost" just in case).

You have been warned.

## Object layout: non-virtual inheritance

If you inherit from base classes, and they have a vptr, you naturally have as many **inherited vptr** in your class.

The question is: When will the compiler add a vptr to a class that already has an inherited vptr?

The compiler will try to avoid adding redundant vptr:

```
struct B { 
    virtual ~B(); 
};

struct D : B { 
    virtual void foo(); 
};
```

Here `B` has a vptr, so `D` does not get its own vptr, it reuses the existing vptr; the vtable of `B` is extended with an entry for `foo()`. The vtable for `D` is "derived" from the vtable for `B`, pseudo-code:

```
struct B_vtable { 
    typeinfo *info; // for typeid, dynamic_cast
    void (*destructor)(B*); 
};

struct D_vtable : B_vtable { 
    void (*foo)(D*); 
};
```

The fine print, again: this is a simplification of a real vtable, to get the idea.

## Virtual inheritance

For non virtual single inheritance, there is almost no room for variation between implementations. For virtual inheritance, there are a lot more variations between compilers.

```
struct B2 : virtual A {
};
```

There is a conversion from `B2*` to `A*`, so a `B2` object must provide this functionality:

- either with a `A*` member
- either with an int member: `offset_of_A_from_B2`
- either using its vptr, by storing `offset_of_A_from_B2` in the vtable

In general, a class will *not* reuse the vptr of its virtual base class (but it can in a very special case).